# PHP preg_replace escape ampersand in backreference regex

Tags: php, regex, backreference

Ok, I've checked and looked, but today my SearchFU is not strong. I am encountering an error with backreferences in some Regex `preg_replace('~$\s*<div>([^<]*?)</div>$\s*~me', '\1', $source);` I could really use a hand with. The expression finds `<div>` tags and returns just the content removing the tag and enclosing linefeeds. ie:

```
<td>
        <div>some value</div>
    </td>
```

becomes

```
<td>some value</td>
```

Everything works fine until `<div>&nbsp;</div>` which causes:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in D:\wamp\www\processfile.php(18)
: regexp code on line 1 Call Stack: 0.0010 143600 1. {main}()
D:\wamp\www\processfile.php:0 0.0350 170328 2. preg_replace()
D:\wamp\www\processfile.php:18 Fatal error: preg_replace(): Failed evaluating 
code:   in D:\wamp\www\processfile.php on line 18 Call Stack: 0.0010 143600
1. {main}() D:\wamp\www\processfile.php:0 0.0350 170328 2. preg_replace()
D:\wamp\www\processfile.php:18
```

If I remove the \1 backreference, the expression will happily erase all the content in the div tags, but seems to want to parse it as a new expression.

Is there a way around this, or should I just pre-process the &'s before this line gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `e` modifier at the end of your regex. It causes the replacement to be `eval()`'ed. Remove it:

```
preg_replace('~$\s*<div>([^<]*?)</div>$\s*~m', '\1', $source);
```

See the [PHP docs for PCRE pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Bam! Thank you. I knew it would turn out to be something simple I'd overlooked. I've been pouring over those docs for 3 days now.